# What method should I use to see whether my categories are well-encoded by my variable?

Tags: classification

In order to test some linguistic hypotheses, a friend of mine looked at some words in some text and tries to see what tests can one do to predict in which category the word belongs.

The data format is the following:

- Columns: Category, Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4
- Rows: each row corresponds to a word in that text

As someone who has a small background in stats and data science, I am trying to help find "which pattern of variables can predict the column category?".

I tried to use the DecisionTreeClassifier from sci-kit learn by restricting its depth, but I don't understand the nodes of the plot and I don't really know what I am really looking for... Any insight would be quite helpful.

The goal is not to predict and generalize on new data, it is only to understand the structure of the current dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split your data into train, validation and test sets and then train a model to predict the category?

The model could be an LSTM or a transformer encoder. It would receive the words and, for each word, predict its category; it's what in NLP is called "sequence labeling".

Then, you could evaluate the results of your model in your test set and, with the confusion matrix, you could try to identify problems in your category coding.

If you want to also incorporate the values of [Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4], you could concatenate them to the word embedding of their associated word.